# How to auth google cloud API from Java in the same way I authenticated with gcloud CLI

Tags: gcloud

Using gcloud command line I can do the following operation

```
gcloud builds describe 74f859e9-d621-4632-b6dd-XXXXXXXX
```

However I wish to use the Google Cloud API from Java, now as I understand the GCloud CLI is not using a service account, it is using a user account. How can I use the same authentication from Google Cloud Java API to do this same operation to describe a build?

Answer (score 2):

Google provides decent documentation that explains how to use its SDKs (Client Libraries) with all of its services.

Here's the [Cloud Build client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/libraries) documentation. Pick your preferred language and go.

If you can't use one of Google's SDKs, then you can write code directly against the underlying API. Google's [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) is an excellent tool for navigating all Google's services. Here's [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest) and [`projects.builds.get`](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds/get) which I think (!?) maps to `gcloud build describe`. You can confirm that by running `gcloud builds describe --log-http` to see which underlying calls are made.

Code that doesn't access user data (data owned by a user account), should run as a Service Account. Code that accesses user data or operates on behalf of a user, should use the OAuth flow for the user and use an OAuth Client ID. This is what `gcloud` does. As a program operating on behalf of users, it authenticates you the user using a regular OAuth flow but it operates using an OAuth Client ID against a hidden backing project. Your code should probably just run as a service account.